# FreeMarker List how adding, and removing items works?

Tags: freemarker

I looked up everywhere, didn't see any help?
how to make a list in FreeMarker?
how to add items in the FreeMarker list?
how to remove items in the FreeMarker list?

in freeMarker with HTML!!

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying collections in templates is not supported (by design). The collections should be already what you need to display, more or less. Only "more or less", because you can do these (and maybe more that I missed here), but these create a completely new list (but with avoiding actual copying internally), instead of modifying the original:

- Only keep items that satisfy a condition: `myList?filter(it -> it.important)`
- Take a segment of a list: `myList[pageNumber*10 ..* 10]`
- Concatenate lists: `myList + myOtherList`
- Map each list item to something else: `myList?map(it -> it.user)`

With above, you can fake the basic list modifying operations, but it's not a good idea to do so in general. Like `<#assign myList = myList + [newItem]>` could be used to add an item. But it's not a good practice to do that, because if you add hundreds of items to a list like that, that list will be slow to iterate through.